# Llenar un campo definido como foráneo de manera automática MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

tengo un pequeño dilema, tengo creadas estas dos tablas, la tabla **acudientes** tiene una llave foránea llamada **Estudiante_ID** la cual esta referenciada al la llave primaria de la tabla **Estudiantes**,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una vez explicado eso, estoy insertando datos desde un programa que cree en java, para poder insertar los datos en la tabla acudientes debo añadir manualmente un valor en el campo **Estudiante_ID** lo cual es engorroso porque tendría que cambiar el código cada vez que quiera añadir un nuevo registro, me gustaría saber si hay una posibilidad de insertar un código para que me traiga el valor de la llave principal automáticamente.

teniendo en cuenta que debe tomar la un valor de la llave primaria que aun no esté asociado a un registro anterior.

```
INSERT INTO `acudientes` (`Id_Acudiente`, `Estudiante_Id`, `Nombre_Acudiente`, `Direccion`, `Correo_Electronico`) VALUES (NULL, 'Aqui es donde deseo añadir el valor de la llave principal automaticamente', '" +D.getNombreAcudiente()+"', '" +D.getDireccionResidencia()+"', '" +D.getCorreoAcudiente()+"')";
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Aunque la explicación que das es algo confusa, me parece que la mejor forma de resolver esto no es desde Java, sino desde la base de datos, programando un TRIGGER que inserte el nuevo en la tabla dependiente.

Comment: @A.Cedano disculpa las molestias la verdad soy un poco inexperto en este tema, no se si tal vez me podrías indicar una guía de como realizar dicho trigger?

Comment: Primero tienes que explicar con claridad si lo que se requiere es insertar una fila en acudientes cada vez que se inserte un estudiante o si es otra cosa. En preguntas como esta es muy importante que se explique el contexto con la mayor claridad posible.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que tu dices, 
mira tengo un formulario en el cual se introducen los datos del estudiante y de su acudiente, pero esos datos van a dos tablas diferentes, la de "estudiantes" y la de "acudientes",  el estudiante por ejemplo tiene un id = 1, entonces el acudiente tiene un campo que se llama "estudiante_id", ese campo debería ser igual a 1, para que el acudiente se relacione con el estudiante que se esta añadiendo, entonces lo que no se es que colocar en el insert del campo estudiante_id de la tabla "acudientes" para que me tome el valor del estudiante que se acaba de añadir.